# Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelector(...).val is not a function.... error javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Buen dia, tengo un error que no sé como solucionarlo. Y no solo es eso, sino tmb cuando uso ***addEventListener***. Es como si no reconociera la existencia de ese input...
Tambien intente poner un código arriba, luego debajo... ¿A que se debe?

```
//// archivo chat.php

   <div class="cfd"></div>

//// archivo chat.js

  var htmle ='';
  htmle +=  ` <div class="contderecha" id="contderecha" >
  <input class="meninput" type="text" placeholder="mensaje">
  <button id="meneviar" onclick="envmens()">ENVIAR</button></div>`;

  document.querySelector('.cfd').innerHTML = htmle;




  function envmens(){

    var mensaje = document.querySelector('.meninput').val();
                    
////                   {EL RESTO DEL CODIGO}  

  }
```

Comment: creo que el .val() esta por demas

Comment: si quieres obtener el valor de tu input seria así                                                          var valor = document.getElementById("idInput").value;